# Programming a series

Tags: java, math, series

I'm having trouble with my [exercise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jT1ef.png).

I'm supposed to write a program, which calculates this series and and which gives out the value every loop. The series also needs to break if the change of the series value is lower than 10^-5 in a loop.

I hope my explanation was understandable so far.

This is what I came up with:

```
public static void main(String [] args) {

    double sum = 0;
    double summand;
    double k = 1;

    do
    {
        summand = 1.0/Math.pow(k, 2);
        sum = 6 * (sum + summand);
        k++;
    }

    while (summand > 1E-5);
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

Now I need help, since I'm very new to Java and I have no clue whether this is right or wrong.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Have you tried your code? Did it do something you didn't expect? What does it do?

Comment: Console says: 4.9328148858994196E246, but I think it should be more than 1 line? I don't know :/

Comment: Move the `System.out.println` inside the `do`-`while` loop

Comment: If you want to print something "every loop", then you need a print statement inside the loop. Currently you only have a print statement at the end.

Comment: I expect that the `sum = 6 * (sum + summand)` line is wrong - `sum = sum + 6 * summand` would be more likely to be correct.

Comment: If you need to keep track of the change of the series from one loop to another, you need a variable to store the value of the previous iteration and compare it with the value of the current iteration in the `while` instead of comparing the summand alone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `sum` line is wrong - as written you're cumulatively multiplying your value so far in *every iteration*, whereas you should be able to see from the original question posed that the factor of six only applies once.

You need:

```
sum = sum + 6 * summand
```

or alternatively leave the multiplication by 6 until *after* the summation, which more closely matches the given formula:

```
do {
    summand = 1.0 / (k * k);
    sum += summand;
} while (summand > 1e-5);
sum *= 6.0;
```

Comment: Thank you! This + putting the println inside the loop did it.

Answer (score 0):

Just move the `System.out.println(sum)` inside the loop.

```
public static void main(String [] args) {

    double sum = 0;
    double summand;
    double k = 1;

    do
    {
        summand = 1.0/Math.pow(k, 2);
        sum = 6 * (sum + summand);
        k++;
        System.out.println(sum); // <-- here it's right
    }

    while (summand > 1E-5);
}
```

That way it will be printed for every iteration of the loop.